# import javax.validation.constraints.notblank not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I am trying to use @NotBlank in my code and it required the dependency and import of `javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank`. However, the import just does not work after I put in the dependency, any guidance would be appreciated.

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Java Class

```
package com.educative.ecommerce.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private @NotBlank String categoryName;

    private @NotBlank String description;

    private @NotBlank String imageUrl;
}
```

The `import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;` is showing error of Cannot resolve symbol 'validation'

Comment: Remove `javax.validation` dependency, add `spring-boot-starter-validation`. Restart application. Only adding the API (like you did) won't work as it is only an API not an implementation. The `spring-boot-starter-validation` includes both the API and an Implementation. Depending on which version of Spring Boot you use the `@NotBlank` might or might not be available due to the version of `javax.validation` being used/supported.

Comment: @M.Deinum just tried what you mentioned but the import is still not working. I am using spring-boot 2.7.1

Comment: Try to refresh your dependencies, the jar might be borked. Else remove the import and let your IDE help you import the right one.

Answer (score 2):

The `@NotBlank` from package `javax.validation.*` is only available from version [2.0](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html) of the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have an older dependency then this should not be available under the above package but you can still find this annotation inside `org.hibernate.validator.constraints` with the following import:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
```